# Access outside the local host

Tags: angular, angular-cli

How can I serve my angular project other than local host ?

I tried using `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200` this complies without any error.

But when I enter another ip like `ng serve --host 192.168.255.1 --port 4200`, I am getting the following error. I am choosing this IP beacuse I would like to serve my application in private IP using openVPN

**

> Error
>   Provided host 192.168.255.6 could NOT be bound. Please provide a different host address or hostname

**

**Versions**

```
 - npm 5.5.1
 - node 6.10.3
 - angular-cli global 1.7.1 and local 1.0.0
```

Comment: According to the error message, you cannot use that host.

Comment: @JuniorGantin even If I try other ip .,it doesn't work either !!

Comment: What's wrong with 0.0.0.0? Are you just randomly picking IPs or how could you try with other IP?

Comment: I am trying to use a OpenVPN..,I have vpn server and I would like to run this angular project in the VPN IP

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Running `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200` is correct.

Specifying `--host 0.0.0.0` means "listen on every available network interface". This will allow you to access your angular project outside of localhost.

To access it from another computer/device:

1. Run `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200`
2. Find the IPv4 Address of the computer running `ng serve`

   - E.g. On Windows enter `ipconfig | findstr /i "ipv4"` in command prompt
3. Navigate to `http://[IP found in step 2]:4200`

Comment: I would like to use a Private IP, like a vpn server..I am using openvpn app and I have a openvpn server with a ip. If I can serve the project in the vpn ip, then I can use that Ip.that was my question ?

Comment: I haven't used it with OpenVPN. What happens If you run `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200`, then navigate to `http://[IP assigned by open VPN]:4200` on another computer which is connected to the same VPN server?